# What is the easiest way to capture widget output to string in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, widget

I know it's very easy in case of simple widget: `$var = widget();`

But in case of complex widgets, e.g. ActiveForm I don't know easy way. I have to use several lines of code:

```
ob_start();
widget::begin();
......
widget::end();
$var = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Maybe somebody knows more easy way?

Answer (score 0):

you can contain the widget in a partial.

```
    $widgetContents =  $this->renderPartial('_fancy-widget', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'otherParam'   => $otherParams
    ]);
```

and all the widget related code you can place into `_fancy-widget.php`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
public function ###(){
    ...
    $layout = self::renderWidgetBegin();
    $layout .= ...;
    $layout .= self::renderWidgetEnd();
    ...
}

private function renderWidgetBegin()
{
    Widget::begin([]);
}

private function renderWidgetEnd()
{
    Widget::end();
}
```

But do not forget, writing the code into a variable will not work, the rendering of the widget starts at the place where the code is declared